# NIntegrate::nlim: * is not a valid limit of integration

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

The following numerical integral within a numerical integral:

```
NIntegrate[ Exp[
-NIntegrate[ 1/(y - (1 - Exp[-(5/6) + (2 y)/3])), 
{y, z, 1}]] , 
{z, -(3/2) ProductLog[-(2/(3 E^(5/6)))], 1}]
```

gives "NIntegrate::nlim: y = z is not a valid limit of integration" error messages prior to giving an estimate 0.250255.

How might I revise my code to avoid the errors?  If the estimate is not valid, please explain why to me.  Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

To ensure that the inner integral never attempts to evaluate before `z` has a numeric value, use

```
int1[z_?NumericQ] :=
 NIntegrate[1/(y - (1 - Exp[-(5/6) + (2 y)/3])), {y, z, 1}]

int2 = NIntegrate[Exp[-int1[z]], 
 {z, -(3/2) ProductLog[-(2/(3 E^(5/6)))], 1}]

(* 0.250255 *)
```